# Why my lscpi command not found?

Tags: system, synaptic

When I try to check my VGA like this:

```
lscpi | grep VGA
```

I get this error:

```
No command 'lscpi' found, did you mean:
Command 'lscpu' from package 'util-linux' (main)
Command 'lscp' from package 'nilfs-tools' (universe)
Command 'lspci' from package 'pciutils' (main)
lscpi: command not found
```

I've installed `pciutils` from Synaptic, and I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You mixed up 2 letters: lspci

Answer (score 17):

It is `lspci` and not `lscpi`.

See what terminal says:

```
No command 'lscpi' found, did you mean:
...
Command 'lspci' from package 'pciutils' (main)
```

Comment: whoops thats my mistakes 
im sorry
and thank you so much...